# Building VirtualBox modules in Gentoo

Tags: virtualbox, gentoo

I have a gentoo installation, where I previously issued `make mrproper` inside `/usr/src/linux`.

I wanted to install VirtualBox modules so I copied `/boot/System.map` and `/boot/config` to `/usr/src/linux` (the config was copied to /usr/src/linux/.config).

I then ran:

```
 emerge -1 =app-emulation/virtualbox-modules-4.3.32
```

Which issued the following warning:

```
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-3.18.25-gentoo-r1'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /var/tmp/portage/app-emulation/virtualbox-modules-4.3.32/work/vboxpci/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /var/tmp/portage/app-emulation/virtualbox-modules-4.3.32/work/vboxpci/.tmp_versions/*

  WARNING: Symbol version dump ./Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.
```

emerge didn't fail, but when it finished, I failed to load the module:

```
 # modprobe -v vboxdrv
insmod /lib/modules/3.18.25-gentoo-r1-09-07-2015/misc/vboxdrv.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Exec format error
```

Can anyone give me an advice how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you most likely have the module signing option enabled in the kernel.
VirtualBox modules are not automatically signed and everytime I build a new kernel I rebuild the modules and sign them.

If that is the case - type into terminal the following (if you embedded the kernel config in proc):

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_MODULE_SIG
```

If you didn't embed the kernel config, find your kernel configuration - it may be in `/usr/src/linux/.config` or `/etc/kernels/kernel-config-<the-corresponding-kernel-version>`

For example, you should see the following or similar output (YMMV):

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=y
# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA1 is not set
# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA224 is not set
# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA256 is not set
# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA384 is not set
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_SHA512=y
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_HASH="sha512"
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY="certs/signing_key.pem"
```

Depending on what hash function is chosen, you should use the same hashing function to sign your modules.
There is a utility called `sign-file`.
In earlier versions this `sign-file` was located in `/usr/src/linux/`, as for `4.5` kernels it is now located in `/usr/src/linux/scripts/` (again YMMV).

Having signed modules enabled and actually booting a system with signed modules `should` usually mean that you already have a generated key and a x509 file (you can generate a signing key yourself).

Executing the following command:

`/usr/src/linux/scripts/sign-file sha512 /usr/src/linux/certs/signing_key.pem /usr/src/linux/certs/signing_key.x509 /lib/modules/<your-kernel-version>/misc/vboxdrv.ko`

should effectively sign your modules and should be ready for `modprobe`.

Locate the x509 file and your signing key, and replace the paths in the command above.

- FYI there are 4 virtualbox modules that need signing - `vboxdrv`, `vboxnetflt`, `vboxnetadp` and `vboxpci`.

[Link to the official Gentoo Module signing article](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Signed_kernel_module_support)